# how do i forbid the pipeline on gitlab when warning detected by dart_code_metrics reach certain amount?

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci, static-analysis

I'm using dart_code_metrics for lint test, how do i forbid the pipeline on gitlab when warning detected by dart_code_metrics reach certain amount?

This is the script om currently using:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  # - build
  - test
  # - deploy
before_script:
  - flutter clean
  - flutter pub get
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

code_quality:
  stage: test
  # tags:
  #   - flutter
  image: "cirrusci/flutter:stable"
  before_script:
    - pub global activate dart_code_metrics
    - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
  script:
    - metrics lib -r codeclimate  > gl-code-quality-report.json
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json
test:
  stage: test
  # tags:
  #   - flutter
  image: "cirrusci/flutter:stable"
  before_script:
    - flutter pub get
    - pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
    - pub global activate junitreport
    - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
  script:
    - flutter test --coverage
    - genhtml coverage/lcov.info --output=coverage
  coverage: '/lines\.*: \d+\.\d+\%/'
  artifacts:
    name: coverage
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage
    reports:
      junit: report.xml
```

EDITED:

the output of gl-code-quality-report.json was like below:

```
{"type":"issue","check_name":"maximum-nesting-level","description":"This method has a nesting level of 6, which exceeds the maximum of 5 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_management/domain/usecase/SendSubManagementRequestUsecase.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":7,"column":3},"end":{"line":61,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"59993c63f8f1d9467d82b29527726c77"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"cyclomatic-complexity","description":"This method has a cyclomatic complexity of 27, which exceeds the maximum of 20 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/controller/HistoryPageViewModel.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":90,"column":3},"end":{"line":296,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"8cfa962ce15b32b130289076f407ae8d"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"cyclomatic-complexity","description":"This method has a cyclomatic complexity of 26, which exceeds the maximum of 20 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/controller/DeviceOverallPageViewModel.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":40,"column":3},"end":{"line":331,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"80372c845392ad7035c29867cbe673ad"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"maximum-nesting-level","description":"This method has a nesting level of 9, which exceeds the maximum of 5 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/controller/DeviceOverallPageViewModel.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":40,"column":3},"end":{"line":331,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"021e0c56368d8e67414381546f1ab15f"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"cyclomatic-complexity","description":"This method has a cyclomatic complexity of 22, which exceeds the maximum of 20 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/controller/GroupDetailPageViewModel.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":37,"column":3},"end":{"line":372,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"22a66ed322d4249f37f1c2e058de89f7"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"maximum-nesting-level","description":"This method has a nesting level of 7, which exceeds the maximum of 5 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/controller/GroupDetailPageViewModel.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":37,"column":3},"end":{"line":372,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"81532d7118b1de5d9ec56162c76b92ff"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 281 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/page/GroupDetailPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":19,"column":3},"end":{"line":316,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"3e658604a193d549b8f4636920d0fd09"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 616 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/lesi_display/presentation/page/HistoryPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":20,"column":3},"end":{"line":651,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"b5d6efa9421e921a976bce60c1001a96"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"maximum-nesting-level","description":"This method has a nesting level of 6, which exceeds the maximum of 5 allowed.","categories":["Complexity"],"location":{"path":"lib/features/core/data/repositories/MyFirebase.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":47,"column":3},"end":{"line":114,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"3e3dc0388e9170a4ba51ce6810d0519a"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 228 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/auth/presentation/page/ResetPasswordPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":22,"column":3},"end":{"line":254,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"389a81c52dc649d2fbff209ae0ed69f2"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 204 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/auth/presentation/page/SettingPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":17,"column":3},"end":{"line":226,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"7a79c4556f9fb778c0f34ef46615b55a"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 555 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/auth/presentation/page/SignUpPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":44,"column":3},"end":{"line":621,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"5fb25f05e1db240b94c591c353de8517"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 219 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/auth/presentation/page/ChangePasswordPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":41,"column":3},"end":{"line":265,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"3ff3509f7a9622a865df4b1c888a5d20"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 352 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/auth/presentation/page/UserProfilePage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":39,"column":3},"end":{"line":392,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"02fd160a313535cb6575e7d73abb6368"}�
{"type":"issue","check_name":"long-method","description":"Long method. This method contains 225 lines with code.","categories":[],"location":{"path":"lib/features/auth/presentation/page/SignInPage.dart","positions":{"begin":{"line":27,"column":3},"end":{"line":266,"column":4}}},"severity":"info","fingerprint":"0c6e34f7270108f1fb8d9c5ce0ed5cbb"}�
```

Comment: What amount exactly are you referring to? Is it a percentage, a number, or ?  Is there a way to output the results from this tool? What is the format of the output -- can you give an example?

Comment: @sytech I've updated some detailed about the output, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script to read your code quality report json file and count the occurrences of issues -- fail the job when the count exceeds an expected count.

If each offense is on a separate line, you can maybe even just use `wc` to count the number of lines.

```yaml
  script:
    - metrics lib -r codeclimate  > gl-code-quality-report.json
    - |
      report_lines="$(wc -l gl-code-quality-report.json | cut -f1 -d" ")"
      if [[ $report_lines -gt 20 ]]; then
          echo "more then 20 issues found"
          exit 1  # fail the job
      fi
```